# ExecutorService.submit, wait for already scheduled similar instances

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm having an `ExecutorService` (or atm a subclass to `ThreadPoolExecutorService`) that I pass tasks to with `submit(Runnable r)`.

Sometimes the same task will be (re)submitted while it's still running, and then I would like the second submit to wait for the first one to finish. I.e. queued. How would be a preferrable way to do that? Only if the submitted task is already running it should be queued, otherwise it should be executed directly.

The returned `Future<>`s will be used to sometimes cancel the tasks.

Something like this;

```
    Runnable r = new LengthyRunnable();

    Future<?> f1 = submit(r); //should start to run
    Future<?> f2 = submit(r); //should be queued and wait for f1
    Future<?> f3 = submit(r); //in case f1 hasnt finished, and f2 is queued, should remove f2 from the queue and take it's place
```

I have subclassed ThreadPoolExecutorService and I'm usind beforeExecute and afterExecute to keep track of the tasks, but it's becoming difficult... Should I use something other then a `ThreadPoolExecutorService`?

Answer (score 0):

I would make `LengthyRunnable` a recurring task (with a suitable pooling interval) which checks whether it needs to run again.  That way you can be sure it not running multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove enqueued f2 task when f3 is enqueued ad f2 hasn't yet started. However ExecutorService doesn't expose access to the queue since the underlying implementation might not be even asynchronous. ThreadPoolExecutor has an underlyign queue but doesn't actually expose it :)

If you don't want to simply make a schedulable /recurrent task as someone suggested than you might consider the following.

Create a WorkPerformer Runnable. Pass it some sort of BlockingQueue, i.e. LinkedBlockingQueue. The queue would be used to enqueue some sort of LengthyTask that you need to perform.

In a calling code you would create a synchronsied block that would peek the queue - if the f2 is there and the f1 is still running (the WorkPerformer would have some sort of synchronised flag) you'd dequeue the f2 and enqueue the f3.

It is hard to suggest anything more / better without knowing what your intentions behind this are.